# Why use ImageIO can't get BufferedImage from URL

Tags: java, url, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

imageURL: https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBB77GLfY75FNWL&w=720&h=2048&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQI0duFYFcmydWNutbwmSk2DfOmHcDrhPfsMJTUoEObbWkVzYUtrHgCuN_LFrWcPRzJi6jPgbn80oFs0Kj_WrdROjdnJkjbnS5-UJv9l9cJyhKCWS-lr-MXlc263Ul3Txe-VFqXfRrA6BOjt4DF-Sww2&ext=best

```
URL url = new URL(imageURL);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

or

```
URL url = new URL(imageURL);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
```

the result **image** is null? why?

Comment: Make sure the link you provided is a valid image file. It seems that the current link is linking to a file with extension of `.php`.

Comment: it seem to be [webp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP)

Comment: The `.php`  extension isn't relevant here, as long as the output is good. The problem is (as @penuel says), that the image is in WEBP format. See my answer below, with links to the format spec and a WEBP-plugin for Java ImageIO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ImageIO.read(URL)` does support reading images from URL like you describe, however, it does support only a limited set of image formats. Built-in formats are JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP and WBMP. There are plugins for many other formats, like TIFF, JPEG 2000, etc.

The problem is that the linked image is not in any of the built-in formats, it's in [WEBP format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/), a new image format created by Google, and which does not have very widespread use yet. The reason it displays fine in your browser (and mine :-) ), is most likely that you are using Chrome, and Chrome has built-in support for WEBP.

There's at least one [WEBP ImageIO plugin](https://github.com/lonnyj/webp-imageio) available. If you build and install this plugin, your code above should work and read the image just fine. There should be no need to invoke `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` if the plugin is on class path when you launch your application.

Comment: Everyone is right , and are a great help for me ( including other respondents )

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the URL your provided is linking to a valid image file format such as `jpg`, `png`, `bmp` and so on.

Your current URL is linking to a `.php` file which is obviously not an image.

**For example:**

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{     
    Image image = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/ac/bb/d4/acbbd49b22b8c556979418f6618a35fd.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(236, 306);
    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
    frame.setVisible(true);                 
}
```

Comment: ImageIO.read(URL) url do not have to be pictures(jpg,png...), yes or not

Comment: @penuel I will be surprised if it do not need to be an image. (jpg, png..etc). So I will say yes, it should be an image. Think about this, if it is a file like `.php` which is supposedly a web file, how is the JVM going to decipher what image to get out from it. A web page can contain text, links, multiple image, tables..

Comment: @penuel If it solves your current problem, you may accept the solution by clicking the tick beside the answer.

Comment: thank you,If there are no other better answer, I will accept this. But what I really need to this url(maybe is webp(https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/)) into a BufferedImage (Java)

Comment: @penuel *Of course* it has to be a picture. An image. You are trying to load an image.

Comment: @penuel I don't think java support webp image format. To load other image formats, you may use external java libraries.

Answer (score 0):

When I open the link in Firefox, it attempts to download a file called "safe_image.php". It works in Google Chrome, so there's something weird going on in the headers or something for that URL. Is there any way you can host the image elsewhere?

**Edit:** Your image appears to be in the WebP format. ImageIO does not support this format natively, so you will need a library like [webp-imageio](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio).

Install that library and see if your code works. `ImageIO` should automatically find the plugin when you run `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()`.

Comment: no,but It can be stored as. JPG, then open by image

Comment: So I did some looking around, and I found the library you need. It's not loading because it's webp format.

Comment: @NighttimeDriver50000 In order to work with webp-imageio, OP will need other link libraries.