# Why does the same image (edit: PNG) produce two slightly different byte arrays in Java?

Tags: java, image, javafx, steganography

I am writing a simple application and one of the features is the ability to serialize an object to an image so that the user can share a photo of their project with the build instructions embedded within it. Currently the other user can drag-and-drop the image into a JavaFX ListView and a listener will execute some code to decode and parse the embedded JSON.

This works fine if the image is stored locally, but I also want to allow users to drag and drop images from a browser without having to save them locally first. To test this I linked a working image in a basic HTML file so I could render it in Chrome.

Originally I was using the path to the file taken from the Dragboard, but when the image is coming from a browser I need (I think) to be able to accept the image directly, hence the overloaded decode() method below.

The problem I am having is that I am ending up with two slightly different byte arrays depending on whether the image comes from a browser or from somewhere in my main local storage. I don't know enough about images within Java (or in general) to understand why this is and haven't been able to find answers elsewhere. The browser sourced drag-drop produces a different enough byte array that I can't decode the message 100% properly, and therefore cannot deserialize it to an object. However, if I right click and save the browser based image, it loads correctly.

I have included a reproducible snippet and a test image below. My JDK is the most recent version of Amazon Corretto 8.

Reproducible snippet:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.WritablePixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApp extends Application {
    private static final int OFFSET = 40;
    private ListView<String> listView;
    private GridPane gridPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        listView = new ListView<>();
        gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.addRow(0, listView);
        setDragDropAction();
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 250, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

// the same drag-drop logic I am using in my project
    private void setDragDropAction() {
        gridPane.setOnDragOver(event -> {
            if (event.getDragboard().hasFiles() || event.getDragboard().hasImage()) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        gridPane.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            List<File> files = event.getDragboard().getFiles();
            try {
                if (!files.isEmpty()) {
                    String decoded = decode(files.get(0));
                    System.out.println(decoded);
                } else if (event.getDragboard().hasImage()) {
                    Image image = event.getDragboard().getImage();
                    String decoded = decode(image);
                    System.out.println(decoded);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    // decode using the file path
    public String decode(File file) throws IOException {
        byte[] byteImage = imageToByteArray(file);
        return getStringFromBytes(byteImage);
    }

    // this results in a different byte array and a failed decode
    public String decode(Image image) {
        int width = (int) image.getWidth();
        int height = (int) image.getHeight();
        PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
        byte[] byteImage = new byte[width * height * 4];
        WritablePixelFormat<ByteBuffer> format = PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance();
        reader.getPixels(0, 0, width, height, format, byteImage, 0, width * 4);

        return getStringFromBytes(byteImage);
    }

    private String getStringFromBytes(byte[] byteImage) {
        int offset = OFFSET;
        byte[] byteLength = new byte[4];
        System.arraycopy(byteImage, 1, byteLength, 0, (offset / 8) - 1);
        int length = byteArrayToInt(byteLength);
        byte[] result = new byte[length];
        for (int b = 0; b < length; ++b) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i, ++offset) {
                result[b] = (byte) ((result[b] << 1) | (byteImage[offset] & 1));
            }
        }
        return new String(result);
    }

    private int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
        return b[3] & 0xFF
                | (b[2] & 0xFF) << 8
                | (b[1] & 0xFF) << 16
                | (b[0] & 0xFF) << 24;
    }

    private byte[] imageToByteArray(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image;
        URL path = file.toURI().toURL();
        image = ImageIO.read(path);
        return ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }

}
```

Another attempt at the decode method using SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage() which is also not working:

```
// Create a buffered image with the same imageType (6) as the type returned from ImageIO.read() with a local drag-drop
public String decode(Image image) throws IOException {
        int width = (int) image.getWidth();
        int height = (int) image.getHeight();
        BufferedImage buffImageFinal = new BufferedImage(width, height, 6); // imageType = 6
        BufferedImage buffImageTemp =  SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        Graphics2D g = buffImageFinal.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(buffImageTemp, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();
        return getStringFromBytes(((DataBufferByte) buffImageFinal.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData());
    }
```

Images showing the changes in the data:

[Corner of image. Dissimilar pixels are highlighted in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep2fo.png)

[image: First 12 bytes showing the difference]

Example image for testing:

[image: Example image for testing]

The decoded testing message should print out ("This is a test message for my minimal reproducible example". Dragging the image from the browser does not work, saving the image locally and drag-dropping it does.

Comment: What types of images are they? What are the file extensions?

Comment: They are all PNGs.

Comment: @Reti43 thanks for your suggestions on improving the question. I've edited the first snippet so that it can be compiled and reproduce the issue I am having, and a test image at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I followed up on your thoughts/suggestions @Reti43 and I believe it is related to the difference between `ImageIO.read()` and `new Image()`. It looks like new Image() loads the image in with pre-multiplied alpha, while ImageIO.read() gives me a BufferedImage without pre-multiplied alpha. In cases where alpha > 0 I can reverse this effect, but the data is lost irreversibly where alpha = 0, as it does for several areas in the sample image I provided. I haven't yet figured out how to force `new Image()` to load not pre-multiplied but if I can I think that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment from the OP, `event.getDragboard.getImage()` loads an image with premultiplied alpha, while `ImageIO.read()` does not. One simple way to circumvent that is to get the url from the event (regardless of how the image is drag and dropped) and use `ImageIO.read()`.

```
gridPane.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
    if (event.getDragboard().hasUrl()) {
        try {
            URL path = new URL(event.getDragboard().getUrl());
            String decoded = decode(path);
            System.out.println(decoded);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

With the following modifications

```
public String decode(URL url) throws IOException {
    byte[] byteImage = imageToByteArray(url);
    return getStringFromBytes(byteImage);
}

private byte[] imageToByteArray(URL url) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    return ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
}
```

Note that loading from an url supports only a limited set of formats, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884305/why-use-imageio-cant-get-bufferedimage-from-url).

Comment: Thanks for your help! For the time being the app only supports PNGs so `event.getDragboard().getUrl()` works perfectly.